# How to insert in linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm having problem with two tables at the time of insert. The tables were created as follows:

I have a table "Page" that has a relationship with another table "Content" so that the FK "Page" falls within the "Content"

By the time I insert a new content, there is already an index on the table "Page" I want to put in the "Content" realize why a table scan select "Page" the correct line. The problem is that it's time to take a `InsertOnSubmit` the content. it automatically is also creating a new index on the "Page".

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `Page` Entity has a one to many relation with the `Content` entity, therefore each Page has a lot of Contents and each Content falls into only One Page, so the Page entity must has a list of Contents and the Content entity must has a property of type `Page` that represents the page reference instead of the foreign key `PageId`, so you didn't need to retrieve the id of the page in order to add a new Content, as follows:

```
[Table]
public class Page
{
    ...
    private EntitySet<Content> _contents;
    [Association(Storage = "_contents", ThisKey = "Id", OtherKey = "PageId")]
    public EntitySet<Content> Contents
    {
        get { return _contents; }
        set { _contents.Assign(value); }
    }
    ...
}
```

For the Content entity:

```
[Table]
public class Content
{
    ...
    [Column]
    int PageId{ get; set; }
    EntityRef<Page> _page;
    [Association(Storage = "_page", ThisKey = "PageId", 
      OtherKey = "Id", IsForeignKey = true)]
    public Page Page
    {
        get { return _page.Entity; }
        set { _page.Entity = value; }
    }
 }
```

Whenever you need to inert a new Content, you have to pass a page reference like this:

```
 Page pageReference = //Get By its id or whatever
 //or
 Page pageReference = new Page { Id = 1, name = " ",....}; 
 Repository.Add( new Content{ Id = 1,...,Page = pageReference });
```

Note that: the add method is just do an `InserOnSubmit` to the entity.

So whenever you want to insert a new content you can attach any page or add any new page just from the page entity it self not from Content, and you didn't need to retrieve the id of the page in order to tell'em what is the page that will have this content just define the relation as objects relations not as the foreign keys.

Comment: in fact, is the page that has a lot of content, so when I insert a new content I needed to say what is the page that will have this content, making it retrieves the id of the page, which in fact I'm not getting, as that when I recover, it adds another page at the time of SubmitChanges ()

Comment: I showed you the basic idea in my answer you should understand it and apply it in your domain and i did it this waay as i understand it as possible as i could and why you shouldn't say that in your question and it is not so different, it the same idea, you should define a property called Page ( a reference to the Page entity) for each Content, so when you add a new Content just add a reference to its page you don't need to retrieve the page id since you did the mapping as EntitySet and EntityRef. i will edited my answer for you and if any thing else feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you need to explain this abit better but if I understand you correctly you create a content that goes inside a page.
The Key here is to create the page retrieve its ID then add the content to that page.